# TikZ Loop through array of arrays

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, foreach

I would like to loop over an array and access each x- and y-coordinate separately, because I want to modify the coordinates before using them on a node.

Currently it is only working when inserting the coordinates directly in the foreach loop, but my second example using an array is not working.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

         \def\myarr {
          (1.0, 1.1),
           (0.5, 1.5),
           (1.5, 2)
         }

        \foreach \x/\y in {1/3, 2/7, 3/8} {
            \node () at (\x,\y) {\x and \y};
        }

        % Not working
        %\foreach \x/\y in {\myarr} {
        %    \node () at (\x,\y) {mynode};
        %}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How can I use an array to achieve the same result?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Would you please provide a complete and compilable example we can immediately start working with? Adding the boilerplate code is tedious work, but could have already been done by the asker.

Comment: Would redefining `\def\myarr {1.0/1.1,0.5/1.5,1.5/2}` be acceptable?

Comment: Ups, now there is less code than before. Minimal compilable means it starts with `\documentclass{...` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @AlexG Sorry, I hope it's fine now.

Comment: @Bordaigorl Yes, as long as the coordinates are clearly identifiable it's fine for me. But redefining the array does not seem to work, too.

Comment: First, tikz arrays use double braces, and it needs to be run through `\pgfmathparse` to convert `{a,b,c}[0]` into `a`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thank you for your help. Could you please provide a more detailed code example? As I am new to tikz I have difficulties following you.

Comment: This works: `\foreach \X in \myarr {
            \node () at \X {mynode};
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop over coordinates, i.e. `\foreach \X in \myarr { \node () at \X {mynode}; }` works in your example. If you want to read out the `x` and `y` coordinates, you may do

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\GetX(#1,#2)#3{\def#3{#1}}
\def\GetY(#1,#2)#3{\def#3{#2}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

         \def\myarr {
          (1.0, 1.1),
           (0.5, 1.5),
           (1.5, 2)
         }

        \foreach \X in \myarr {
            \edef\temp{\noexpand\GetX\X\noexpand\myx
            \noexpand\GetY\X\noexpand\myy}
            \temp
            \node () at \X {\myx\ and \myy};
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This shows how `\myarr` is parsed.  Actually, the first parenthesis are ignores, then the commas inside the parenthesis are ignored.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
   \def\myarr {{
          (1.0, 1.1),
           (0.5, 1.5),
           (1.5, 2)
         }}
  \verb|\myarr[0]| = \myarr[0] 

  \pgfmathparse{\myarr[0]}\pgfmathresult

  \pgfmathparse{\myarr[1]}\pgfmathresult

  \pgfmathparse{\myarr[2]}\pgfmathresult

  \pgfmathparse{\myarr[3]}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: demo]